# A Problem on Inverse Trigonometric Functions and Differential Equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, solution-verification, inverse-function

> $f(x)=\left(\sin \left(\tan ^{-1} x\right)+\sin \left(\cot ^{-1} x\right)\right)^{2}-1,\ |x|>1$
>
> If $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}=\frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}\left(\sin ^{-1}(f(x))\right)$ and
> $y(\sqrt{3})=\frac{\pi}{6}$, then $y(-\sqrt{3})$ is equal to :
>
> **Options:**
>
> $1. \quad-\frac{\pi}{6}\\
> 2. \qquad \frac{2 \pi}{3}\\
> 3. \qquad \frac{5 \pi}{6}\\
> 4. \qquad\frac{\pi}{3}$

It can be easily shown that $f(x) = [\sin(\tan^{-1}x) + \sin(\cot^{-1}x  )]^2 -1 = \frac{2x}{1+x^2}$.

$\frac{d}{dx} (\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}) = \frac{-2}{1+x^2}$

Now $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{ d(\sin^{-1}f(x))}{ dx} = \frac{-1}{1+x^2}$ from which we get $y = - \tan^{-1}x  + C. $

Now $y (\sqrt 3) = \frac{\pi}{6}$. So $C= \frac{\pi}{2}$.

So $y = \frac{\pi}{2} -  \tan^{-1}x $.

$y(-\sqrt 3) = \frac{5\pi}{6}$

Have I gone wrong any where? Can anyone please check my solution?

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax rather than posting image. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, your answer is correct.

Answer (score -2):

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}(\sin^{-1}f)= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-f^2}}\cdot \dfrac{df}{dx}=P\cdot Q \;;$$

$$P=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-(2x/(1+x^2))^2}} = \dfrac{1+x^2}{1-x^2} $$
Differentiating by Quotient rule

$$Q=\dfrac{2}{(1+x)^2}; \quad PQ=\dfrac{2}{1-x^2};\; $$

EDIT1:

Stopped too early by mistake.  Continuing,

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{1}{1-x^2}$$
Integrates to
$$y=\log_e\sqrt {\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}} +c$$
given
$$ y(\sqrt3)=\dfrac{\pi}{6}$$

$y$ is not real, constant of integration cannot be evaluated. For this result ***no option available.***

Comment: Can you please elaborate how did you get that?

Comment: Upto $ f(x)=\frac{2x}{1+x^2} $ I got the same result as you. use Quotient /Chain Rule next.

Comment: i think you have made  any mistake. Please check once again. @Narasimham

Comment: It is a 4 5 lines' problem. It won't take more than 5 minute to recheck. It would be great if you do it now.

Comment: Sorry about delayed answer.

Comment: I have already got the answer  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3786107/two-methods-are-giving-two-different-answers-to-the-this-differential-equation/3786798#3786798.    And your solution does not seem to be correct to me.

Comment: Edited to complete the answer.